# Почему не работает такой элементарный код? Что вообще происходит с браузерами?

Tags: javascript, консоль

```js
console.clear();

var st = new String();
st.concat("Строка");
console.log(st.toString());
```

Выдаёт пустую строку.

Comment: concat() возвращает результат конкатенации, а не меняет строку на которой применяется. фактически это оператор `+`, а не `+=`. т.е. `st=st.concat("Строка")` дало бы правильный результат https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: Похоже перепрограммировал на Delphi...

Comment: В делфи был бы тот же результат при использовании такого же инструмента =) Скорее просто вы не сталкивались в делфи со static class методами.

Comment: Или так st += st.concat('Строка'); разницы нету + или += потому как по дефолту st='' и вообще var st = ""; короче, экономьте на быстродействии

Comment: Вообще использовать конструкторы примитивных типов примерно никогда не нужно. https://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes

Answer (score 2):

Все методы `String` **НЕ МЕНЯЮТ** исходную строку.

Так как в примере выводится исходная строка - вывод закономерен.

Для решения достаточно выводить результат выполнения метода:

```js
console.clear();

var st = new String();
var res = st.concat("Строка");
console.log(res.toString());
```

Comment: Добавлю, что методы String возвращают новую строку, а старая остается неизменной как сказано в ответе.